# Getting a block inside main content

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

I have created a Drupal page which consists of the main content of my page, text plus a photo, a nested box which is just a button and a views block which is the third element. What I want to do though is make the nested box go below the views block which is only possible if I add the views block to the content page class but I am not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using Panels to structure your site?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I am not using Panels, I think. I am using Drupal 7.54

Answer (score 0):

You can place your blocks in the "content" region and then you can arrange them in the correct order on the blocks page, `admin/structure/block`.

See screenshot below for Drupal 7 example. 
[image]

Comment: This does not work for me, I sent the custom block right after the Main page content although still the button remains above it. On the other hand it will work if I do it from manage display and If i put after content although it does not get it for the specific node id but it gets it for the whole page display.

Comment: Go back to the `admin/structure/block` and see what position it is in "Content"? See if your changes saved and then clear your caches. This is definitely the way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by what position? And of course I saved my changes.

Comment: Above or below "Main page content"

Comment: I placed it below Main Page Content